# Prime number checkers

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.5

I have a problem with my code that my teacher ask my to check the prime numbers but he does not allow me to use If-Else function . Here is my code:

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while (i % n != 0):
        while (n % i == 0) and ( n != i):
            print("False")
            break
        i += 1
    while (i == n):
        print("True")
        break
number = int(input("Please enter a certain number: "))

print(is_prime(number))
```

But the problem is when i print out the result, it's a little bit weird with the numbers which are not a prime number:

```
Please enter a certain number: 10
```

`False 
False 
True 
None`

How would i solve this problem? I just need one answer: True or False. Thank you for your helps!!!

Answer (score 0):

To be short: let your function to **return** a value, not to print it.

```
def is_prime(n):
    i = 2
    while (i % n != 0):
        while (n % i == 0) and ( n != i):
            return False
        i += 1
    return True
number = int(input("Please enter a certain number: "))

print(is_prime(number))
```

### Explanation:

As soon as you find out that `n` is not prime (line `while (n % i == 0) and ( n != i):`) you return `False`. The function is left at this moment so you do not need `break`. If `n` is not found to be divisible by any `i` you return `True`.
The `True` or `False` is now the result of the function and you can print it or assign to a variable and use somewhere else. E.g.

```
x = is_prime(12) // x is False now
```